# Does anyone know what is the way to get the entire directory structure of the cloud account locally?

Tags: wolfram-cloud

So when I publish the notebooks go in the folder:

`Home\Published\...`

When I attend any online tutorial the notebooks are automatically copied into:

`Home\Copied Files\...`

When I do some quick evaluation without making any saves they get saved into:

`...\Unnamed\...` (I don't know what is the root directory here)

Similarly for `Deployed` contents and `Trash`.

So my question: is there a way I can in my local notebook get up to date content in all directory including directory structure of my cloud account? So I don't have to go to a browser to do a login and manually browse the cloud folders to see what is there.